# What kind of 'actions' would you typically do in the 'run' method of a module in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

tI know when the `run` method gets invoked (after the injector is created) and that you can inject only instances, but I was wondering, what would you typically do/want in this method? What is the point of this method?

The documentation talks about a 'kickstart', what is meant by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular offers two functions which let you execute code during your modules initialization.  First, mid-way through initialization `config` is called.  Then once Angular is done initializing it calls `run`.  So `run` is often compared with the main function provided in many languages since it's the function that starts things off (kickoff meaning "start off" or "get running").

**Thus, `run` is called just once and executes before the rest of your code**.(except after `config`)  Unlike `config` it's called after the injector is created, as you noted, so you can inject any services/providers into it- and call functions they provide.

Note that because `run` is called so early there is no scope other than rootScope so you can't inject in `$scope` but you can inject `$rootScope`.  Because of this some use `run` to setup global variables on `$rootscope` (for good or for bad...)

From http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module :

> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations
>      and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>      into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>      of services before they have been fully configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get
>      executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the
>      application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run
>      blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during
>      application run time.

Since `run` is called before anything else it is sometimes used for authentication.  Here's an example of doing that- you'll see `config` is used to set up routing and then `run` does some initialization including creating a `watch` that must be established during initialization : http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

So, `run` or `config` are good for one-time initialization especially when you want to ensure that initialization occurs before any of your other code runs.